# Website is having trouble loading script files ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

The website previously worked fine but now the scripts files,styles,and images are not being loaded. Chrome shows error stating Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500(Internal Server Error). Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    </head>
       <body>
           <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- 
               toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("StarGSP", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Suspicious Activity", "Index", "Suspicious", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                F
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Trooper Activity", "Index", "Trooper", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Privacy Policy", "Index", "PrivacyPolicy", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - StarGSP</p>
    </footer>
</div>


@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) bootstrap.css

Comment: Do you have your JS files loaded via the BundleConfig.cs file or is everything defined in the HTML? IE: <script src="scripts.js"></script>

Comment: I dont have bundleconfig file is mvc asp.net application I have packaged.config

Comment: You keep referring script files, but your code shows css files. Which one is it?

Comment: They include script files and css files

Comment: Please add whole HTML. This would provide a better context.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this problem is that when referencing script or files the script have to go at the bottom and the files have to go at the top of the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
  **@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")**

 </head>
   <body>
       <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- 
           toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("StarGSP", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Suspicious Activity", "Index", "Suspicious", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            F
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Trooper Activity", "Index", "Trooper", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Privacy Policy", "Index", "PrivacyPolicy", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="container body-content">
@RenderBody()
<hr />
<footer>
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - StarGSP</p>
</footer>
</div>
 **@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")**

 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```